# php - strip a string of everything except ascii and emoji

Tags: php, regex, emoji

I'd like to clean a string, leaving only ASCII characters **BUT** also, I'd like to keep emoji's!

Currently, we have a dumb whitelist approach:

`preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F,☠,♥)]*/','', $text);`

Is there a way to let a large group of emoji's through the filter?

Currently our php configuration does not have `mbstring` values set. e.g. we *don't* have `mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8`. Not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: grab the unicode range of emotions & put it just like what you did for ascii.

Comment: what does the incoming string looks like??

Comment: @Andrew - The incoming string is unknown. It's a mash up of user-inputted data and text from a CMS. for example it could be the subject of a email that includes the users first name (which they gave us). i.e. it's dangerous text.

Comment: @Andrew : -(|||)(^^) ♥

Comment: haha I was thinking something like `trim($str, "a..zA..Z0..9 \t\n\r")`...and thats should left out the ascii and emoji :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `(`, `,`, `)` have no special meaning in a character class, and if you use the quantifier `*`, your pattern will succeed at each position in the string (with an empty match).

If you want to preserve emoji's, you only need to put them in your negated character class. Obviously instead of putting them one by one in the character class, use ranges, like this:

```
/[^\x20-\x7F-☠♥]+/u
```

You can select the ranges you are interested by here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji

Note that since your are dealing with unicode characters, you must use the u modifier.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Using a range for the characters is neat! It makes it quite readable.